# Mis-matching color profiles when copying layers from one document to another

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm attempting to copy some color layers from 1 document to another.  When I drag the folder of color layers over I get this message:

"Are you sure you want to convert colors to a destination document with a color profile that does not match the current RGB working space?"

I do not wish to convert the colors...  Therefore...

[image: Color Profile Mismatch]
Ok.  Seems like maybe one document has the profile sRGB, and the other document has profile Adobe RGB...  So, I view EDIT>COLOR SETTINGS on each document thinking they must not match.   BUT, when I view both under color settings, both documents have the color settings sRGB...

What am I missing?  Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Wyatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT>COLOR SETTINGS

— is not document setting, but globaly Photoshop.

Think One document was created on another machine and Second on yours.

Mostly I'm ignoring this message. But if you want to change try: **EDIT>Assign Profile** OR **Convert to Profile**.